# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I received this error while making a script that scans a url and fetches a response code, then I received this error. I searched far and wide over Stack Overflow, Google, etc. All answers to this error were not related to this situation. This can benefit users that are stuck with this same situation.

```
for dirs in dds_dirpath:
        if responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "200" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "201" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "202" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "203" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "204" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "205" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "206" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "207" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "208" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "226" or responsecode(dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]) == "401":
            print "[   \033[1;32;40mOK\033[1;37;40m   ] ", dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]
        else:
            print "[ FAILED ] ", dds_host + dds_dirpath[dirs]
```

Thank you, all help is appreciated. I do not consider this a me-problem as I have found unanswered questions in this same situation.

Comment: Error is pretty self explanatory, **dirs** variable you use seems to be **str** type. Try casting into int, if they are just stored that way. Also searching your title literally gives tons of questions and answers and they are what you are looking for.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate two different types of data.convert them using str() or int() appropriately.You can also check the type using type() function.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do to solve your problem is to replace dds_dirpath[dirs] with just dirs. dds_dirpath[dirs] doesn't make any sense because dirs variable inself will iterate over dds_dirpath and will take *values*, not indices from that list

```
for dirs in dds_dirpath: 
    if responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "200" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "201" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "202" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "203" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "204" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "205" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "206" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "207" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "208" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "226" or responsecode(dds_host + dirs) == "401": 
        print "[ \033[1;32;40mOK\033[1;37;40m ] ", dds_host + dirs 
    else: 
        print "[ FAILED ] ", dds_host + dirs
```

I can't ignore the fact you are requesting some URL 11 times (!) in the if condition. It is bad because website administrators doesn't like very frequent requests from the same IP and will probably ban your IP

You should do something like this

```
for dirs in dds_dirpath:
    if responsecode(dds_host + dirs) in ["200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "226", "401"]: 
        print "[ \033[1;32;40mOK\033[1;37;40m ] ", dds_host + dirs 
    else: 
        print "[ FAILED ] ", dds_host + dirs
```

Do you really get your response code as a string, not int?